# Steps in XSTREAM

Tags: xml, xstream

I want to read an XML file into Java objects.
Can XStream do this? 
I do not have a XML-Schema for my file.
Can anyone suggest me any alternatives ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, XStream can do that in short, but not as simply as xml in, object out. You'll have to construct the object that'll correspond to the xml's nodes/attributes.

A quick tutorial on XStream's website for doing so [here](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html).